# Should non-English organizations/ministries/governments (as authors) be translated into English in APA 7th edition citations?

Tags: naming, translation, apa

Should I translate the name of my country's government/ministry into English for references and in-text citations in a publication using APA 7th edition guidelines? My paper is in English, and I'm unsure if translating official names maintains accuracy or if I should keep them in the original language. How do APA guidelines address this, and what are the best practices for ensuring clarity and consistency in citations involving non-English governmental entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Do not translate the names of authors.

You only translate the title of the work (in square brackets after the original title; do not italicize the translated title) and you *transliterate* non-Latin names (e.g. Chinese or Russian). If you want, translate or explain the insitution in text, e.g. "The Spanish Ministry of Foreign Affairs wrote ... (Ministerio de Asuntos Exteriores, 2023)."

There is [a post on the APA style blog](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2014/11/lost-in-translation-citing-your-own-translations-in-apa-style.html) where this is explained in a comment by Chelsea Lee, the Instructional Lead of the APA:

> Q:  If I understand correctly, my source in French, adapted for an English article, should look like this in my reference page:
>
> Centre canadien de lutte contre l’alcoolisme et les toxicomanies [Canadian Centre on Substance Abuse]. (2005). Conception d’un outil servant à mesurer l’incidence de la durée du séjour du bénéficiaire sur les résultats de traitements: aperçu. [Designing a tool to measure the impact of the length of stay of the beneficiary on treatment results: an overview]. ...
>
> A: You do not need to translate the name of the author in the reference list. In the text, you can translate the name of the author into English if you want to, but the citations should be in French because that is how the author is listed on the published article.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and help!